# googlecharts doesn't show 2nd chart

Tags: dashboard, google-visualization

i got the problem that my dashboard doesn't show the second chart. i tried different versions and read several threads, but cannot solve it by my own. the datatables are filled with data from a mysql-db and are correct (both work fine on dashboards with only one datatable and one chart!).

heres my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

     // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['controls']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">




function drawChart() {
        dashboard1 = createDashboard1();
        dashboard2 = createDashboard2();
}

function createDashboard1() {


var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn("string", "Name");
    data.addColumn("number", "Wert");
    data.addColumn("string", "Datum");
    data.addRows([[" Apple iTunes ",1054771,"2014-07-04"],
                  [" Apple iTunes ",1139032,"2014-07-08"],
                  [" Apple iTunes ",1141890,"2014-06-23"],
                  [" Apple iTunes ",1140293,"2014-06-24"],
                  [" Apple iTunes ",1105672,"2014-07-07"],
                  [" Apple iTunes ",925948,"2014-06-26"],
                  [" Apple iTunes ",1054772,"2014-07-05"],
                  [" Google Play Store ",1285270,"2014-07-07"],
                  [" Google Play Store ",1281289,"2014-07-05"],
                  [" Google Play Store ",1279384,"2014-07-04"],
                  [" Google Play Store ",1261568,"2014-06-20"],
                  [" Google Play Store ",1270873,"2014-06-26"],
                  [" Google Play Store ",1269927,"2014-06-24"],
                  [" Google Play Store ",1268064,"2014-06-23"],
                  [" Google Play Store ",1286660,"2014-07-08"]]);

var datePicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
        'containerId': 'control1',
        'options': {
        'filterColumnLabel': 'Datum',
            'ui': {
            'labelStacking': 'vertical',
                'allowTyping': true,
                'allowMultiple': false,
                'allowNone': false
        }
    }
});

var dataPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'control2',
    'options': {
        'filterColumnLabel': 'Name',
            'ui': {

            'labelStacking': 'vertical',
                'allowTyping': true,
                'allowMultiple': true,
                'caption': 'Wert wählen',
                'selectedValuesLayout': 'belowStacked'
        }
    }
});

var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'containerId': 'chart1',
    'chartType':'PieChart',
    'view': {'columns': [0,1]
    }       
});

function setOptions(wrapper) {
    wrapper.setOption('height', 400);
    wrapper.setOption('width' , 600);
    wrapper.setOption('chartArea.width','80%');
    wrapper.setOption('animation.duration',0);
    wrapper.setView({'columns':[0,1]});
    wrapper.setOption('colors',['#E20074','#FDD167','#EDA95A','#9F5C97','#64B9E4','#427BAB','#408F9A','#BABD5A','#000000','#A4A4A4','#7C7C7C','#6C6C6C','#EDEDED','#4B4B4B','#D0D0D0']);
    wrapper.setOption('title', 'Verteilung AppStores');
    wrapper.setOption('tooltip',{'text':'percentage'});
};

setOptions(chart);

 var dash = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).
 bind([datePicker],[dataPicker]).bind([dataPicker],[chart]).
 draw(data);
}

function createDashboard2(){

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn("string", "Datum");
data.addColumn("number", "Google Play Store");
data.addColumn("number", "Apple iTunes");
data.addRows([["2014-06-20",1261568,0],
              ["2014-06-23",1268064,1141890],
              ["2014-06-24",1269927,1140293],
              ["2014-06-26",1270873,925948],
              ["2014-07-04",1279384,1054771],
              ["2014-07-05",1281289,1054772],
              ["2014-07-07",1285270,1105672],
              ["2014-07-08",1286660,1139032]]);

var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'containerId':'chart2',
    'chartType':'ColumChart'                
});

setOptions(chart);

function setOptions(wrapper) {
    wrapper.setOption('height', 400);
    wrapper.setOption('width' , 600);
    wrapper.setOption('chartArea.width','80%');
    wrapper.setOption('animation.duration',0);
    wrapper.setOption('colors',`['#E20074','#FDD167','#EDA95A','#9F5C97','#64B9E4','#427BAB','#408F9A','#BABD5A','#000000','#A4A4A4','#7C7C7C','#6C6C6C','#E`DEDED','#4B4B4B','#D0D0D0']);
    wrapper.setOption('title', 'Verteilung Android (Version)');
    wrapper.setOption('tooltip',{'text':'percentage'});
};


var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).
draw(data);
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="dashboard">
        <table>
            <tr style='vertical-align: top'>
                <td>
                    <div id="control1"></div>
                    <div id="control2"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div style="float: left;" id="chart1"></div>
                    <div style="float: left;" id="chart2"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

any suggestions what went wrong?

regards, olli

Comment: The first thing that pops out at me is that you're creating two dashboards with the same target element.  I think placing your controls and charts in a table like that, with two separate datasets is going to make your life needlessly complicated.

Comment: i took this code as an [example](https://gist.github.com/battlehorse/1242360), where he also has 2 datatables and 2 charts for the same target

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors?  I'm having trouble helping you because I don't have your php application or data, so I can't run this.  If you replaced the php with it's output I might be better able to help.  The link to the original example was helpful, though.

Comment: no i don't get any errors. i edited my question and added the php output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of your problem is that when you changed the example, you restructured the dashboard and controls so that chart1 had two controls bound to it, and chart2 had none.  Because of this, chart2 was never bound to a dashboard.  Not a problem in general (a chart can exist on it's own), but you're trying to use the dashboard to draw the chart.

Once I fixed that I also found that your dashboard2 function was not really assigning your options to your chart (you declared that inside a function and then never called it?) so I restructured that a bit, added the data to the chart (before it was sent to the dashboard) and voila!  Here's a working version of your page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>
      Google Visualization API Sample
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
        google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['controls']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">




        function drawChart() {
            dashboard1 = createDashboard1();
            dashboard2 = createDashboard2();
        }

        function createDashboard1() {


            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn("string", "Name");
            data.addColumn("number", "Wert");
            data.addColumn("string", "Datum");
            data.addRows([[" Apple iTunes ",1054771,"2014-07-04"],
                          [" Apple iTunes ",1139032,"2014-07-08"],
                          [" Apple iTunes ",1141890,"2014-06-23"],
                          [" Apple iTunes ",1140293,"2014-06-24"],
                          [" Apple iTunes ",1105672,"2014-07-07"],
                          [" Apple iTunes ",925948,"2014-06-26"],
                          [" Apple iTunes ",1054772,"2014-07-05"],
                          [" Google Play Store ",1285270,"2014-07-07"],
                          [" Google Play Store ",1281289,"2014-07-05"],
                          [" Google Play Store ",1279384,"2014-07-04"],
                          [" Google Play Store ",1261568,"2014-06-20"],
                          [" Google Play Store ",1270873,"2014-06-26"],
                          [" Google Play Store ",1269927,"2014-06-24"],
                          [" Google Play Store ",1268064,"2014-06-23"],
                          [" Google Play Store ",1286660,"2014-07-08"]]);

            var datePicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
                'containerId': 'control1',
                'options': {
                    'filterColumnLabel': 'Datum',
                    'ui': {
                        'labelStacking': 'vertical',
                        'allowTyping': true,
                        'allowMultiple': false,
                        'allowNone': false
                    }
                }
            });

            var dataPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
                'containerId': 'control2',
                'options': {
                    'filterColumnLabel': 'Name',
                    'ui': {

                        'labelStacking': 'vertical',
                        'allowTyping': true,
                        'allowMultiple': true,
                        'caption': 'Wert wählen',
                        'selectedValuesLayout': 'belowStacked'
                    }
                }
            });

            var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                'containerId': 'chart1',
                'chartType':'PieChart',
                'view': {'columns': [0,1]
                }       
            });

            function setOptions(wrapper) {
                wrapper.setOption('height', 400);
                wrapper.setOption('width' , 600);
                wrapper.setOption('chartArea.width','80%');
                wrapper.setOption('animation.duration',0);
                wrapper.setView({'columns':[0,1]});
                wrapper.setOption('colors',['#E20074','#FDD167','#EDA95A','#9F5C97','#64B9E4','#427BAB','#408F9A','#BABD5A','#000000','#A4A4A4','#7C7C7C','#6C6C6C','#EDEDED','#4B4B4B','#D0D0D0']);
                wrapper.setOption('title', 'Verteilung AppStores');
                wrapper.setOption('tooltip',{'text':'percentage'});
            };

            setOptions(chart);

            var dash = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).
            bind([datePicker],[dataPicker]).bind([dataPicker],[chart]).
            draw(data);
        }

        function createDashboard2(){

            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn("string", "Datum");
            data.addColumn("number", "Google Play Store");
            data.addColumn("number", "Apple iTunes");
            data.addRows([["2014-06-20",1261568,0],
                          ["2014-06-23",1268064,1141890],
                          ["2014-06-24",1269927,1140293],
                          ["2014-06-26",1270873,925948],
                          ["2014-07-04",1279384,1054771],
                          ["2014-07-05",1281289,1054772],
                          ["2014-07-07",1285270,1105672],
                          ["2014-07-08",1286660,1139032]]);

            var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                'containerId':'chart2',
                'chartType':'ColumnChart'                
            });

            chart.setDataTable(data);

            chart.setOptions( {
                height: 400,
                width: 600,
                chartArea:{
                    width: '80%'
                },
                animation: {
                    duration: 0
                },
                colors:     ['#E20074','#FDD167','#EDA95A','#9F5C97','#64B9E4','#427BAB','#408F9A','#BABD5A','#000000','#A4A4A4','#7C7C7C','#6C6C6C','#E`DEDED','#4B4B4B','#D0D0D0'],
                title: 'Verteilung Android (Version)',
                tooltip:{
                    'text':'percentage'}
            });


            chart.draw();
        }

        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="dashboard">
        <table>
            <tr style='vertical-align: top'>
                <td>
                    <div id="control1"></div>
                    <div id="control2"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div style="float: left;" id="chart1"></div>
                    <div style="float: left;" id="chart2"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: works like charme! so when i want to add a controler to the 2nd chart for example i have to use the dashboard again, right? thank you so far!

Comment: Yes, if you have Controls, you need to have a Dashboard.  Charts can exist on their own.